# Which function is called before all function when a page loads in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm an android studio developer but now working in Flutter. In android studio on Start and OnCreate function are called when an activity starts. But I want to know which function is called first when a page loads in Flutter. Even before the initState().

Comment: Is the main function what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic sequence of events in flutter is actually fairly easy to follow as they're all right there in the code. Let's assume you have a very simple app with just one Stateful Widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the app first starts, some android or iOS specific things happen first. They load up the dart engine and it looks for the `void main()` function (although you don't need to explicitly have void as the return value).

The main function is called, in which `runApp` is called with an instance of `MyApp`. Note that `MyApp` doesn't have a constructor here but it could.

Then, flutter takes over and does whatever it needs to do to get started (look into `runApp` if you want more details). Eventually, `MyApp.createState` is called, in which a new instance of `MyAppState` is created. Then, finally, `initState` is called.

An interesting thing to note is that the main function doesn't actually need to call `runApp` right away. It's possible to make the main function asynchronous, and have it do some operations before it calls runApp.

Comment: So the MyApp.createState can be called as a repalcment of onCreate?

Comment: Well, not exactly - they have two different purposes. To be honest, in most cases you probably want to be doing things in initState